# pretty printing of javascript string

Tags: javascript, xml, pretty-print

Here's my problem. I have an xml file that contains some code snippets. I'd love to print that code into my web page in the nice way like the text editors do.

XML FILE (very easy example)

```
<example>
    <codesnippet> i=0; while (i<10) { </codesnippet>
    <codesnippet> j=i*2; i++; } </codesnippet>
<example>
```

I parse the code from the xml file and put it into a Javascript string.
The javascript string will look like

```
"i=0; while (i<10) {j=i*2; i++; }"
```

Is there any library or something that allows me to make it look like this

```
i=0;
while (i<10) {
    j=i*2;
    i++;
}
```

without write everything in javascript?

Comment: JSFiddle's "TidyUp" button can do this; you can check out their source and see how they do it.

Comment: thank you.. i'll look for this.. :)